# Bytes to Int conversion in Python 3

Tags: numpy, type-conversion, python-3.6, literals, hashlib

I have a variable named offset that belongs to  `<class 'bytes'>`.

What I need is to find the difference b/w offset and mapper[hash], here mapper[hash] belongs to `<class 'numpy.int64'>`.

The function I have is as follow :

```
for hash, sid, offset in x:
     yield(sid, int(offset) - mapper[hash])
```

Note : In the original function offset isn't typecasted to int. I have purposely done that to get difference b/w them.

But this is throwing an error saying

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\xf9\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Not surprising, though on **debugging I printed the offset without typecasting** and found the values to ->

```
b'\xcb\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'B\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'T\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

What are the possible solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do these values look reasonable?

```
In [292]: alist = [b'\xcb\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 
     ...: b'B\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 
     ...: b'T\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00']                                                            
In [293]: [np.frombuffer(astr,int) for astr in alist]                                                  
Out[293]: [array([4299]), array([4162]), array([7252])]
```

Looks like each bytestring is 8 bytes, so may be the byte representation of `int64` objects.

Comment: for hash, sid, offset in x:
        val = (np.frombuffer(offset,int))
        yield (sid, val[0] - mapper[hash])

Is it okay, fortunately I am not getting any errors !